# FirebaseStorage - File at URL is not reachable

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage

I have the following error :

> [firebase_storage/unknown] File at URL: file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/DABF3DC5-1ABC-4824-B072-DEAC0F37144D/Documents/myappdir/b42e210-62ed-11ec-9430-f940facba-temp_file.mp4 is not reachable. Ensure file URL is not a directory, symbolic link, or invalid url..

I simply would like to know in which situation can I have the following error ? In other words, which `FirebaseStorage` method is throwing such error and in what kind of situation ?

Because I have used `catchError` on all methods in my code and it didn't catch this error but I see it in my Crashlytics dashboard (I have registered non fatal errors for my beta testers).

The implementation is :

```
UploadTask uploadPostFile({required String filePath, required String uid}) {
    Reference reference = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref()
        .child("content/" + uid);
    return reference.putFile(File(filePath));
  }

 Future<String> getDownloadUrl(String uid) {
    return FirebaseInstance.ref()
        .child("content/" + uid)
        .getDownloadURL();
  }
```

And they are called like this :

```
await uploadPostFile(filePath: "file_path", uid: "uid").catchError((e) {
            print("upload main video file error : $e");
            return e;
          });;
String fileResult = await getDownloadUrl("uid").catchError((e) {
            print("Download main video file error : $e");
            return e;
          });
```

This error happens 1 time / 1000 in my beta app version, I simply need to investigate the error in my code that would lead to such behavior so I can fix it.

### Edit

I am also having this error :

```
[firebase_storage/unknown] An unknown error occurred, please check the server response.. Error thrown null.
```

Can it be linked in any way ? The error itself (`unknown`) doesn't help much to know what this is about...

I am interested in the following questions:

- The method used by FirebaseStorage to throw this error.
- The context of this error (upload / download) `File at URL` that doesn't start by `http`.
- Eventually a sample code that would lead to this error, in order to have a use case scenario that would help me understand easily when this happens.

Comment: The error says that the file cannot be found locally. 

I am going to guess that after you obtain the download link, you download the file and then try to access it. That might be where the error occurs. 

What do you do after `await getDownloadUrl(...`? How do you download the file? Are you sure the file is downloaded correctly? How do you access it after the download?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. After the download i am simply saving the new path on an specific Class and save it in my remote database. I don't try to access it, but why it would be a Firebase Storage error in this case ? If accessing locally, that means the error is raised before upload ? Is there a problem with this path (by syntax i mean) ? When the file doesn't exist before upload this is another error so i know the file exists.

Comment: I see. It is hard to help without the full code and the entire crash report. What I can suggest you is to run in on a simulator, get to the point where you have the video file  and before uploading it you manually delete it using Finder. And debug from there.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. This is the only trace i have from crashlytics and it's not a blocking point but my users sometimes have an upload failure because of this and have to retry.  The whole code is very heavy and complicated (i have a full queuing system with compression / video editing etc...) that's why i asked only about the Firebase Storage error, WHEN this error occurs so i can check better at the "right moment". I have edited the question, what i am looking for is the method throwing this error.

Comment: In case you want to investigate further yourself, this is one place where the error is thrown: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/e9d483222df04f0b3b41bf0f61c30d67e15f387e/FirebaseStorage/Sources/FIRStorageUploadTask.m#L208

Comment: thanks for the links. However i don't know objective-C, i am a flutter dev. Can you help me please to tell where this method is called / used regarding the upload / download ? Feel free to post an answer in this case.

Comment: I am guessing that this method is called when uploading. You can check that the file exists before doing anything with it, and if it does not exist, show an error. I cannot really help you more than this.

Comment: Yes i am already doing that actually (check if the file exist before uploading and if it does not start by http already). Thanks for your time, much apreciated

Comment: A suggestion: Maybe put your app in `runZoneGuarded` and catch + log all otherwise unhandled errors there?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but i already have this setup to catch all errors + an isolate as stated in the documentation. This is how i am getting this one actually because i have never got it during debug, only from release mode with my beta testers from crashlytics (and this is a not a crash).

Comment: Assuming the methods (eg: uploadPostFile) are running async. The exception will be thrown on another thread and your catchError will be efective only during the current thread.